# Mobile nav is offset and height is not taking 100vh

Tags: html, css, menu, height, width

I'm trying to make my nav fill the entire screen (it will be hidden in right corner and slide to the center) but it has this weird margin on the left side.

Also `height: 100vh;` it's not taking 100% view height.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:wght@400;700&family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,400;9..144,700&display=swap");

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 3.5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.open-menu, .close-menu {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

nav {
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<header class="menu">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="links cta">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <button class="close-menu">
          close
      </button>
    </nav>
    <button class="open-menu">
        open
    </button>
  </header>
```

Comment: it's not taking 100% view height because it's parent element header is fixed to height: 3.5rem;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exacly sure why, but using

```
left: 0;
top: 0;
```

solved the problem